# While loop issue when retrieving records from a sql database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Ive been trying to get this working for about 6 hours now and cant seem to find the solution or the error in my code...

Basically the code SHOULD pick up every instance of a date/time that is 2 minutes past the current date/time but for some reason it only returns one instance. Ive tried so many ways of solving this i couldnt possibly write them all down.

I have two methods `removedexpiredusers()` and `getexpiredusersdate()`.

`Getexpiredusersdate()` should retrieve each records date/time added and feed them through to `removeexpiredusers()` which should use that method to filter out which records are two minutes past the current date and if they are delete them.

The two minutes deletion time is purely for testing as the plan is to change this to delete the user account after 24 hours giving the user a temporary account for one day.

Here is my code so far any help appreciated

```
private void removeExpiredUsers()
{
    while (DateTime.Now >= getExpiredUsersDate().AddMinutes(2))
    {
        //remove the user
        dal.spDeleteExpiredUsers(getExpiredUsersDate());
    }
}
private DateTime getExpiredUsersDate()
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime();
    try
    {
        using (SqlDataReader datareader = dal.getUsers())
        {
            while (datareader.Read())
            {
                date = ((DateTime)datareader["DateAdded"]);
                MessageBox.Show(date.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlex) { }
    catch (Exception ex) { }

    return date;
}
```

**EDIT**

Im going to include the stored procedures here also guys

**GetUsers**

```
Create proc spGetUsers
as
Begin
    SELECT * 
    FROM [User]
    ORDER BY Username
End
```

***spDeleteExpiredUsers**

```
Create proc spDeleteExpiredUsers
@DateAdded datetime
as
Begin
    DELETE 
    FROM [User] 
    WHERE DateAdded = @DateAdded
End
```

Comment: You should comment out all the `try-catch` blocks so that we can debug better.

Comment: But the messagebox shows all the users or just the one? Because you return just the last date and only this last date  is checked in the if that executes the delete operation

Comment: @Steve Hi steve, it shows just the one user, should there be a way to feed the other dates through?

Comment: @Steve He is returning a single date but isn't he deleting the details so for every loop he will fetch single but different value??

Comment: If the messagebox shows only one date and you expect to find more than one user then the problem is not here but in the dal.GetUsers() call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you simplyfy this by creating a stored procedure which **deletes** users where based on your logic, i.e.

```
DELETE FROM UserTable WHERE DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),DateAdded) < -1
```

You can then call this stored procedure from your .NET application using [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) (if you want number of rows effected) or just [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) if you don't need any result.

I think it's better to handle something like this in `SQL server`. I tend to only use `C#` if there's some business rules that need to be parsed or applied, before issuing a delete.  If it's a simple Time Comparison that decided on whether a user is removed, then keep it simple.

**EDIT**: I have updeted the SQL, this will delete anyone that was added more that 1 day ago.

Comment: What is the RegisteredDate() function you are using?

Comment: This is just psuedo code, Should be `DateAdded` (now I looked at the code again).

Comment: ChristianDev, will this code then retrive the current date and compare it to the dates from the table?

Comment: I have edited the SQL for you, since that was onlu pseudo.  It will remove anyone with a DateAdded greater than 1 day.  Consider maybe setting a flag **(soft delete)**, instead of a hard delete also.

Comment: All answers were great but this one appears to be the best answer based on performance. Thank you Christian Dev

Answer (score 2):

> Basically the code SHOULD pick up every instance of a date/time that is 2 minutes past the current date/time but for some reason it only returns one instance.

You are actually returning only one date (the last set) in the `getExpiredUsersDate()` method. Use a list instead. Somehting like this:

```
// Change return type to a list of DateTime's
private List<DateTime> getExpiredUsersDate()
{
    // Don't need this
    //DateTime date = new DateTime();

    var dates = new List<DateTime>();

    // The try-catch is unnecessary, 
    // the using-statement will catch all exceptions before the try-catch.
    //try
    //{
        using (SqlDataReader datareader = dal.getUsers())
        {
            while (datareader.Read())
            {
                // Add the date to the list.
                dates.Add((DateTime)datareader["DateAdded"]);

                MessageBox.Show(date.ToString());
            }
        }
    //}
    //catch (SqlException sqlex) { }
    //catch (Exception ex) { }

    // Return all dates.
    return dates;
}
```

And a shorter version could be:

```
private IEnumerable<DateTime> getExpiredUsersDate()
{
    using (SqlDataReader datareader = dal.getUsers())
    {
        while (datareader.Read())
        {
            yield return (DateTime)datareader["DateAdded"];

            MessageBox.Show(date.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `removeExpiredUsers()` you can do something like this with linq:

```
private void removeExpiredUsers()
{
    var toRemove = getExpiredUsersDate()
        .Where(date => DateTime.Now >= date.AddMinutes(2));

    foreach (var date in toRemove)
    {
        dal.spDeleteExpiredUsers(date);
    }
}
```

But you can also do all of this in SQL as mentioned by christiandev.

Comment: `date => DateTime.Now => date.AddMinutes(2)` should probably be `date => DateTime.Now >= date.AddMinutes(2)`

Comment: @DominicKexel Thanks, typed to fast =)

Comment: @Mario hey, the spDeleteExpiredUsers() method requires a datetime to pass to the stored procedure, is there a way of cycling through the list then to pass through to the method each time?